# How do you deal with a :create permission in cancan that's defined by the parent object?

Tags: cancan

Let's say you're writing the software for Blogger.

Each user can create a blog post only if they are the owner of the blog. CanCan would normally define an ability check in this circumstance as:

```
user.can? :create, Post
```

However the user can only create the post if they are the owner of the current blog and there's no way to reference the current blog using only its classname. What I really need to be able to do is:

```
user.can? :create, Post, @current_blog
```

such that in the cancan definitions I can say

```
can :create, Post do |post, blog|
  user == blog.owner
end
```

Is that possible or am I confused in how I'm approaching this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define an ability based on the parent of the current object:

```
can :create, Post, :blog => { :user => user }
```

This will make sure the current user can only create a new Post record for a blog that they are an owner of.

- uses `Post.blog_id` to find parent `Blog` record
- compares `Blog.user_id` field to `current_user.id` field

Also make sure that you are using a `:through` declaration when loading and authorizing your Post resource, so CanCan knows who the parent record is.

```
PostsController:

load_and_authorize_resource :through => :blog
```

See the [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) on GitHub for more detail.

Comment: The :through => :blog in the end was the deal. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> user.can? :create_posts, @current_blog

or

> user.can?:update, @current_blog

instead of

> user.can? :create, Post, @current_blog

. Of course, you probably need to take out `new` and `create` action from `load_and_authorize_resource`. And test "authorization" by yourself

> def new
>   unauthorized! if cannot? :create_posts, @current_blog
>   end

Comment: do you know how you'd deal with the actual ability definition though? it's normally of the form `can :create Post do |post_instance|...` so it's not clear how just passing different variables would work with that?

Comment: For your exemple I would use `can(:create_posts, Blog) do |blog| user == blog.owner end`. So test is maked on @current_blog not Post, but in the PostsController.new .

Comment: I'm not sure that would work as I believe that CanCan indexes the permissions based on the type of the object passed in so if one passed in `blog` it would look at the blog permissions. The way that I've got around it in the end though is to setup a new object: `user.can? :create, @current_blog.posts.new` - that way I can pass in a post object and still read the parent off it

Comment: `@current_blog.posts.new` looks nice but it pollutes `@current_blog.posts` with new post instances. This can be a problem if you want to use it afterwards. Any ideas how to avoid that?